# Meteor Reactive Transform to Show Computed Values

Tags: coffeescript, meteor, reactive-programming

I'm trying to insert a computed value into my template.

So the code goes as follows

```
Template.missions.inProgress = -> Missoins.find { #search query
}, {
    transform: (mission) ->
        mission.progress = calculateTimeLeft(mission.startTime, mission.timeRequired)
        return mission
}
```

The code works, but how I make it reactive so it will update every so often?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your `calculateTimeLeft`. If the results of `Missoins.find` changes the code should adjust to updates since `mission.startTime` and `mission.timeRequired` are different.

If you have a reference to some other reactive value in your `calculateTimeLeft` you may want to convert it to a helper

```
Template. missions.progress_value = function() {
    return calculateTimeLeft(this.startTime, this.timeRequired)
}
```

Then use `{{progress_value}}` in your each loop.

Comment: the `calculateTimeLeft` function is not reactive and uses the results from the "find" function.

Comment: You could try checking `startTime` and `timeRequired` in your html, do they change? It looks like you've done it all right. It sounds a bit weird its not working. Could you provide something I can reproduce?

Comment: here is a reproduction of what I'm trying to do. If you rerender the template it updates: http://pastebin.com/qC55fDhm